# display a list of blob

Tags: list, blob

i have some blobs in my database ,actually i can retrie just one and display it in ImageView and i would like to retire several and give the choice to the user like if he just click at the same button
the image of ImageView change
here is my main class:

there is my mainclass:

```
package com.example.autretest;
import java.util.List;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ImageButton imagebutton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

            addListenerOnButton();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

          final ImageView imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     Bitmap bm = null;
                     List<Bitmap> listbitmap=null;
                    SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter =new SQLiteAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                     mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

                     listbitmap=mySQLiteAdapter.queueAllphoto();
                     int location=2;
                     while (location<listbitmap.size()){
                      imageview.setImageBitmap(listbitmap.get(location));
                     }
                     location++;
                     mySQLiteAdapter.close();





                     //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(content,0,content.length);

                     //image =  new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(content, 0, content.length));


                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }



            });


    }

}
```

then you've got the otherclass SqliteAdapter:

```
package com.example.autretest;



import java.sql.Blob;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;


public class SQLiteAdapter {

    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE_APP = "ma_table";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE_photo = "pictures";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE_plan = "plan";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT_ID = "Content_PK";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT_ID_photo = "Content_PK_photo";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT_ID_plan = "Content_PK_plan";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT_photo = "Content_photo";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT_plan = "Content_plan";


    //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
            "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE_APP + " ("
                    + KEY_CONTENT + " text not null)"+ 
                    "create  table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE_photo + " ("+ KEY_CONTENT_photo + " blob not null)"+" " +
                    "("+  KEY_CONTENT_ID_photo + " INTEGER  not null);" +" ("+  KEY_CONTENT_ID + " INTEGER  not null) "+
                    "create  table " +  MYDATABASE_TABLE_plan + " ("+ KEY_CONTENT_plan + " INTEGER not null)";  


    private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    private Context context;


    int s=0;
    byte[]app_image=null;


    public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
        context = c;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public void DropDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        //On peut faire ce qu'on veut ici moi j'ai décidé de supprimer la table et de la recréer
        //comme ça lorsque je change la version les id repartent de 0
        db.execSQL("DROP DATABASE " + MYDATABASE_NAME + ";");

    }

    public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this; 
    }
    public Bitmap getIcone(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_CONTENT_photo};
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        byte[]image_bytes=null;
        Cursor rslt=null;
         rslt=sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE_photo,columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(rslt.getCount()!=0){
            rslt.moveToFirst();
            image_bytes=rslt.getBlob(rslt.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT_photo));
            Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image_bytes, 0, image_bytes.length);
            return bmp;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public String queueAll(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_CONTENT};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE_APP, columns, 
                null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int index_CONTENT = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT);
        for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()){
            result = result + cursor.getString(index_CONTENT) + "\n";
        }

        return result;
    }
    public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this; 
    }

    public void close(){
        sqLiteHelper.close();
    }

    public long insert(String content){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE_APP, null, contentValues);
    }
    public long insertphoto(byte[] iconebyte){

        // "create  table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE_APP + " ("+ KEY_CONTENT + " text not null)" + 
        //" ("+  KEY_CONTENT_ID + " INTEGER  not null);"+" ("+ KEY_CONTENT_plan + " INTEGER not null)"+
        // String sql="Insert into MYDATABASE_TABLE_APP_photo(KEY_CONTENT_ID_photo,KEY_CONTENT_ID,KEY_CONTENT_photo) values(?,?,?)";
        //executeSql
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT_photo, iconebyte);


        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE_photo, null, contentValues);

    }






    public int deleteAll(){
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE_APP, null, null);
    }



    public int deleteAllphoto(){
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE_photo, null, null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public List<Bitmap> queueAllphoto(){
        Bitmap bitmap;
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_CONTENT_photo};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE_photo, columns, 
                null, null, null, null, null);
        byte[] result = null; 

        List<Bitmap> listbitmap=null;
        int index_CONTENT = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT_photo);
        for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()){
            result = cursor.getBlob(index_CONTENT) ;


        }

        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result , 0, result.length);
        listbitmap.add(bitmap);
        return listbitmap;
    }

    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            //db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);





        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing to know is the number of blobs that need to be shown then after that i created the same number of buttons where i just "setBackgroundRessource"!
here is an example but the images are not blobs but drawables but the idea is the same 
except that you need to convert the blob in a bytearray

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                Button btn = new Button(getBaseContext());
                                btn.setId(k1);
                                final int id_ = btn.getId();
                                LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearscroll);
                                linear.addView(btn, params);
                                final Button btn1 = ((Button) findViewById(id_)); 
btn1.setBackgroundResource(matable[k1]);
```

matable is just an array of all my drawable